# Program that can treat different input forms(int and str) in C

Tags: c, input, int, scanf, fgets

I have to get 3 integers as input from the user. But my program should be able get that input as a string and as 3 separate integers as well.

For example, it should be able work with all of these input formats.

> 1 2 3
>
> 1, 2, 3
>
> "1 2 3"
>
> "1, 2, 3"

Any ideas how I could do this?

Maybe I should use `fgets()` then `sscanf()` and check the return value of that and depending on that do different stuff. But I haven't been able to get it to work.

Thanks!

Comment: "but i haven't been able to get it to work" what have you tried?

Comment: Read up on **strtok_s**, for example [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/blob/master/docs/c-runtime-library/reference/strtok-s-strtok-s-l-wcstok-s-wcstok-s-l-mbstok-s-mbstok-s-l.md).  Generally the scanf family of functions are suited for well formatted input, such as from a file.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to wait for the full string and parse it yourself. Start checking if it is enclosed by double quotes (you can either discard outer spaces or just check first and last character), and if it is store it as a string. Otherwise parse it in order to get the integers (`sscanf()` should do the job).

Comment: PS: post your attempt, otherwise your question will be closed soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get 3 digitgroups separated by any non digits you can try:

```
char vals[3][40];
char *bp=input;
for(n=0; n<3; n++) {
    for(dp=vals[n]; *bp && !isdigit(*bp); bp++);
    for( ;isdigit(*bp); dp++, bp++) *dp = *bp;
    *dp='\0';
}
```

Some checks can be added....